# Set minute steps on mdPicker library angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using this famous material datetimepicker library: https://github.com/alenaksu/mdPickers 
(I can't find the docs though)

```
A demo of this at:
https://codepen.io/alenaksu/details/eNzbrZ/
```

What I need to do is I need steps on the time picker of 15mins interval, so this means any hour can be selected but the minutes can only be selected on 00, 15, 30 and 45.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is not actually an answer to your question, but why you don't use the following one? https://dalelotts.github.io/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it in 1.8.6:

https://github.com/beenote/angular-material-datetimepicker/releases/tag/v1.8.6

It will round the initial input set by ngModel to the nearest valid step. minute-steps= 1, 5, 10, 15, 30... The default step is 5 minutes.

Comment: I tried with v1.8.6 in the index html I added minute-steps="15" to one of the time picker, but I still have the issue. I set the time minutes to 25 and the time hand points to 30 which is correct but when I press OK the value in the timepicker input stays "25" which should be 30.

Comment: I forgot to assign the rounded value. Fixed in https://github.com/beenote/angular-material-datetimepicker/releases/tag/v1.8.7

Answer (score 2):

@Biswas, I was not able to achieve this with the library you mentioned, but was able to do this with another library.

https://github.com/beenote/angular-material-datetimepicker

If the styles/Color Codes for the Date time picker are different from what you already have in your page, you may have to play around with the CSS.

This library has an attribute "minute=steps" where you can set how many steps you want for minute . I have created a plunker to demonstrate that with 15 minute steps.

Note: The time can be selected in this library only through the Clock and I didn't see an option to enter the time in the input box. You can dig further on their Github page above.

http://plnkr.co/edit/ajCWLmG7m79MSjxEf93S?p=preview

HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>mdPickers - date/time pickers for Angular Material</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, 
initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.4/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/ng-material-datetimepicker@1.8.4/dist/material-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <md-content id="content" layout="column" flex ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
  <md-toolbar class="md-whiteframe-z2">
    <div style="text-align: center;">
      <h1>mdPickers</h1>
      <h2>Material Design date/time pickers</h2>
    </div>
  </md-toolbar>

  <md-content flex layout="column" layout-align="center center" layout-padding>
    <h3><a href="https://github.com/alenaksu/mdPickers">https://github.com/alenaksu/mdPickers</a></h3>  
    <md-input-container flex-gt-md="30">
        <label>Timepicker Only</label>
        <input mdc-datetime-picker date="false" time="true" type="text" id="time" short-time="true"
               show-todays-date click-outside-to-close="true"
               placeholder="Time" auto-ok="true"
               min-date="minDate" minute-steps="15"
               format="hh:mm a"
               ng-change="vm.saveChange()"
               ng-model="time">
    </md-input-container>
</md-content>
</md-content>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.6/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.6/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.4/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ng-material-datetimepicker@1.8.4/dist/angular-material-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="https://unpkg.com/ng-material-datetimepicker@1.8.4/dist/angular-material-datetimepicker.min.js.map"></script> -->
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
(function() {
    var module = angular.module("app", [
    "ngMaterial",
    "ngAnimate",
    "ngAria",
    "ngMaterialDatePicker"
  ]); 

  module.controller("MainCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.currentDate = new Date();

  }]);
})();
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hi Vijay, in your demo I tried to set time at 5:40 and it set to 5:40, while it should have set to 5:45 automatically, I think there is a bug in this library.

Comment: Please elaborate. The plunker demo above allows you to select the time and as far as I tested, I was able to select only in 15 minute steps. Let me know the steps to test your scenario.

Comment: please test it again, the thing is the library allows to select in 15 minute steps but saves value in whatever we select.

Comment: @Biswas, The time issue is because "time" variable has the initial time set to current time. I dont think you can do anything about it. If the user selects the minute through the picker , it will only be set to 15 minute steps. The issue happens when the user doesnt select the minutes through the picker and clicks Ok before that.  You will have to write the logic in the ng-change() function to convert it to the nearest 0,15,30,45 , if the user doesnt set the minutes. I have given a brief outline in the plunker. You can take it from there.

Comment: @Biswas, Where you able to get it fixed?